# Binding a function for rl_attempted_completion_function (Readline c++)

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, bind, readline

## Introduction

I'm trying to implement auto-completion for a console application on linux and want to use the GNU readline library for doing so. I have written my custom TrieTrees and already have the autocompletion working on Windows (and by using global variables also on Linux), so I want to reuse most of my current functions. The problem there is that I need more parameters to do the auto-completion than the readline callback provides. So I was tinkering around with  `std::bind` and lambdas, trying to "wrap" the existing functions, but it did not work with both of them.

## Current Code

I tried:

```
auto completer_func = [&](const char* text, int start, int end) {return completer(text, start, end, auto_input, tag_count, mode_names)};
rl_attempted_completion_function = completer_func;
```

in the main function and

and

```
char** completer(const char* text, int start, int end, COMMAND_INPUT& auto_input, std::map<std::string, int>& tag_count, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>& mode_names) {
    // Don't do filename completion even if our generator finds no matches.
    rl_attempted_completion_over = 1;
    // Note: returning nullptr here will make readline use the default filename
    // completer.
    auto cg_func = [&](const char* text_l, int state_l) {return completion_generator(text_l, state_l, auto_input, tag_count, mode_names); };
    
    return rl_completion_matches(text, cg_func);
}
```

calling the completion generator:

```
char* completion_generator(const char* text, int state, COMMAND_INPUT& auto_input, std::map<std::string, int>& tag_count, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>& mode_names) { ... }
```

resulting in the error:

```
error : cannot convert ‘completer(const char*, int, int, COMMAND_INPUT&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::unordered_map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)::<lambda(const char*, int)>’ to ‘char* (*)(const char*, int)’
error :   472 |  return rl_completion_matches(text, cg_func);
error :       |                                     ^~~~~~~
error :       |                                     |
message : initializing argument 2 of ‘char** rl_completion_matches(const char*, char* (*)(const char*, int))’
message :   484 | extern char **rl_completion_matches PARAMS((const char *, rl_compentry_func_t *));
```

I also tried to use the reference of the lambda function:

```
return rl_completion_matches(text, &cg_func);
```

which gave me a very similar error:

```
 cannot convert ‘completer(const char*, int, int, COMMAND_INPUT&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::unordered_map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)::<lambda(const char*, int)>*’ to ‘char* (*)(const char*, int)’
   472 |  return rl_completion_matches(text, &cg_func);
       |                                     ^~~~~~~~
       |                                     |
```

It seems like I would need a function pointer and I dont know how I could get one.

## Readline Default Behavior

The functions are intended to be defined as:

```
char** completer(const char* text, int start, int end)
char* completion_generator(const char* text, int state)
```

and can be used:

```
rl_attempted_completion_function = completer;
rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);

char** completer(const char* text, int start, int end) {
    // Don't do filename completion even if our generator finds no matches.
    rl_attempted_completion_over = 1;
    // Note: returning nullptr here will make readline use the default filename
    // completer.
    
    return rl_completion_matches(text, completion_generator);
```

where the `completion_generator` provides either a `nullptr` if no match was found, or returns the result by calling `return strdup(match.c_str());`

## Conclusio

I'm stuck here and want to avoid using global variables for passing `COMMAND_INPUT& auto_input, std::map<std::string, int>& tag_count, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>& mode_names` to the functions.Your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Readline API sadly doesn't provide for passing a context pointer (as many C-style libraries do, precisely for the reasons you describe). Without it, it's either global variables, or non-portable trickery like runtime-generated machine code thunks. At the end of the day, there's no magic that would allow you to squeeze additional information into the function-pointer-sized piece of data.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but thank you for the quick response! Do you know whether there is a library that would accept a context pointer (and in best case also be cross-platform) for doing auto-completion in the console setting?